# How to stream video over secure connection on iOS

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, stream, mpmovieplayercontroller

I can play a video from a local resource (on the device).
I can stream a video from the unprotected internet.
I **can't** stream from the company intranet (either from internal or externally)

Typical secure company network. Videos are stored in SharePoint 2007 lists (but I have url to the video file).

I've tried:

- MPMoviePlayerController
- MPMoviePlayerViewController
- UIViewView (creating html on fly using the `<video>` tag and video url)

and I can't get anything to work. Heck, I can't even get it to work going directly to the link in Safari on the iPad. The only thing I haven't tried doing is downloading it as a file then playing locally. Due to a host of usability issue this would not be a preferred option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems.

1. `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't support all the challenge authentication which exists in `NSURLConnection`. The solution is to just do a "dummy" `NSURLConnection` somewhere inside your secure area, have it handle all the challenges and set it to store the information for the session. From here on out, `MPMoviePlayerController` or other connections which don't support the ins and outs of SSL requests will use the existing session.
2. A valid intermediate certificate had to be installed on the server. Something I never would have figured out myself. It exists as a small item in one of the guides under Secure connections.

Comment: the second problem, or fix, by using the intermediate certificate, is the solution for answering the SSL challenge. Not the streaming itself.. Right? I mean, that, you can answer the SSL Challenge in a different manner, than using an intermediate certificate, can't you?

Comment: Possibly you can answer the challenge in another way. I stopped digging once I had an answer I could use. The main problem is `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't provide a system for answering challenges. So you need use some other connection to navigate the challenges and set up the session to `MPMoviePlayerController` has doesn't have to deal with any of it. It doesn't really matter how to clear the challenges as long as you do.

Comment: Would you mind adding the code that gives MPMoviePlayerController a dummy NSURLConnection? I have a similar problem and have no idea where to start.

Comment: guys do you have any example how to sort this challenges outside MPMoviePlayercontroller? or did anyone resolved this?

Comment: @nhenrique - Yes. Using an `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` it's a fairly straight forward and well documented process. Look for the `didReceiveChallenge` method in the delegate protocols.