# How to play https:// url video on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

```
    I have a https:// base video url, Please let me know how to play video through MPMoviePlayerController.
I use following code:



MPMoviePlayerViewController * moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
    [target presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

But it is not working. and send ssl error.

Comment: hope it helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374841/how-to-stream-video-over-secure-connection-on-ios

Comment: What is your url? does the file in your url has a movie file extension ?

Comment: yes, this is movie file url https:// like that

Comment: Are you logged in and authenticated with this SSL server you're attempting to stream the video from ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the **`movieUrl of the MPmovieplayer`** is "**string**"

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:movieurl];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = 
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```